# В предложении верно согласование?

Tags: согласование, подлежащее

В предложении:«Она вместе с ним пошли в кино»...или «Она вместе с ним пошлА в кино».
Пишут, если женский род стоит в начале, то лучше и в женском роде согласовать подлежащее....А потом читаю, что если есть «вместе, совместно», то подлежащее в единственном числе...
А если множественное число употребить? Будет очень грубой ошибкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Правильно:**

Единственное число:

Она **ВМЕСТЕ** с ним **ПОШЛА** в кино. Она с ним **пошла** в кино. Он с ней **пошел** в кино.

Множественное число:

**Они** с ним/с ней **пошли** в кино.

**2. Неправильно:**

**Она** вместе с ним **пошли** в кино.  **Он** с ней/с ним **пошли** в кино.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

**РОЗЕНТАЛЬ**  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

**§186. Сказуемое при подлежащем типа брат с сестрой**

п.2. При наличии в конструкции слов **ВМЕСТЕ, СОВМЕСТНО** употребляется **форма единственного числа сказуемого.**  Употребление мн. числа будет ошибкой.

Это вся теория, которая требуется для решения этой задачи. Ссылки желательно давать на официальные справочники Розенталя и ПАС.

Comment: О как: на текст тут плевать, но «желательно» , чтобы он стоял под шапкой Розенталя! :)))) Это, кстати, весьма печально.

Answer (score 1):

В действительности решает не «начало», а смысл.

> Форма множественного числа сказуемого показывает, что в роли подлежащего выступает все сочетание, т.е. действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам, например: *После обеда **Лось с Русаковым пошли** посмотреть склады и магазины* (Т. Семушкин); ***Встали** и **Воропаев с Корытовым*** (П. Павленко).
>
> Форма единственного числа сказуемого показывает, что подлежащим является только существительное в именительном падеже, а существительное в творительном падеже выступает в роли дополнения, обозначая лицо, сопутствующее производителю действия, например: ***Граф** Илья Андреевич в конце января с Наташей и Соней **приехал** в Москву* (Л. Толстой); *...**Пришел Разметнов** с Демкой Ушаковым* (Шолохов).

То есть **число сказуемого выбирается исходя не только из формы подлежащего, но и из смысла!**

> Выбор одной из двух возможных форм согласования сказуемого зависит от смысловой соотнесенности действия и его производителя. Иногда на решение этого вопроса влияет лексическое значение слов, входящих в сочетание, например: ***Мать** с ребенком **пошла** в амбулаторию*; ***Старший брат** с сестренкой **уехал** в деревню*. Ср.: *И **графиня** со своими девушками **пошла** за ширмами оканчивать свой туалет* (Пушкин).
>
> Иногда играет роль порядок слов в сочетании. Ср.: ***Муж с женой пошли** в театр. – **Жена с мужем пошла** в театр* (обычно в рассматриваемых конструкциях при различной родовой принадлежности существительных на первом месте фигурирует более сильный в грамматическом отношении мужской род, например: ***отец с матерью, дед с бабкой, мальчик с девочкой***; поэтому выдвижение на первое место существительного в форме женского рода подчеркивает его роль, а отсюда согласование с ним сказуемого).

Это и есть ваш случай. *Она* здесь — подлежащее, а *с ним* — дополнение, обозначающее лицо, сопутствующее производителю действия. Вопрос на миллион: в каком числе должно стоять сказуемое в предложении, где подлежащее — *она*?

Тем более, в вашем предложении ещё и присутствует слово *вместе*...

> 2. При наличии в конструкции слов *вместе, совместно* употребляется форма единственного числа сказуемого, например: *Операцию **делал профессор вместе с ассистентом***; ***Режиссер совместно со своими помощниками подготовил** новые мизансцены в спектакле*. Ср.: *Еще мальчиком **Русаков вместе со своим отцом** уехал от безземелья с переселенцами в Сибирь* (Т. Семушкин).

Обратите внимание на последний пример, из Сёмушкина: наличие *вместе* важнее даже «смысловой соотнесённости действия и его производителя»!

Все цитаты — https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html                     Тут же и про «вместе»...

Comment: Этот сайт я знаю, но тут ведь про другое. Раз так, мне придётся дополнить ответ.